# How can we find the span of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we find the span of the two vectors
$v_1=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}3\\-4\\5\\7\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
and
$v_2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2\\1\\-5\\-5\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
in $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: It's the set of all possible linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$ by definition.

Comment: Do you mean by c1v1+c2v2 =0?

Comment: I mean it is the set $S=\{c_1v_1+c_2v_2 : c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: **Welcome to the MathSE community!** Please note that in general your question is more favourably received, if _(1) you show also your efforts_ to answer it (this also hints at where you're actually stuck), or motivation to ask the question, or a mixture of effort&motivation; _(2) it's properly formatted_ (in LaTeX, via using MathJax). Take this opportunity to get into it, it certainly pays off, and a quick way goes along editing other questions and answers to copy code snippets from there which suit you best. Finally, you shouldn't be discouraged by the downvotes your first question received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The span of the two vectors $v_1=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}3\\-4\\5\\7\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $v_2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2\\1\\-5\\-5\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ would be the set of vectors $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
such that
$$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z\\w}=av_1 + bv_2=a\pmatrix{3\\-4\\5\\7}\:+\:b\pmatrix{2\\1\\-5\\-5},$$ that is the set of all vectors of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}3a+2b\\-4a+b\\5a-5b\\7a-5b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, which as @Ahmed said represents the set of all linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by finding the span of the two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, but if you're asking what the two vectors span in $\mathbb{R}^4$, it would only be a two-dimensional plane.

It's only a two-dimensional plane because you have two vectors which are linearly independent. We know that they're linearly independent because you cannot write one as a scalar multiple of the other, even if said scalar is a negative value.

Therefore, we can form any vector that lies in a two-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the equation:

$\underline{v}_x=c_1\underline{v}_1+c_2\underline{v}_2 \qquad \qquad c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

The span of two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ is given by the set,
$\{\alpha v_1 + \beta  v_2: \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}\}$ which could be simplified as
$(3 \alpha+2 \beta,−4 \alpha +1 \beta ,5 \alpha −5 \beta ,7 \alpha −5 \beta)$